# GetFileSecurityW always returns File not found

Tags: winapi, unicode, filesystems, ownership

Calls to GetFileSecurityW from VBA always returns "File Not found" even if file handle can be obtained using CreateFileW. Example below

```
  sUnicode = MakeUnicode(szfilename)
    Debug.Print sUnicode
    bSuccess = GetFileSecurityW(StrPtr(MakeUnicode(szfilename)), OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION, 0, 0&, _
                                sizeSD)
    Debug.Print ErrorMsg(Err.LastDllError)


    Const GENERIC_READ As Long = &H80000000
    Const OPEN_EXISTING = &H3
    Const FILE_SHARE_READ = &H1
    Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE As Long = &H20
    Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN As Long = &H2
    Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY As Long = &H1
    Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM As Long = &H4
    Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = &H80&

    Dim Flags As Long, Access As Long
    Dim Disposition As Long, Share As Long

    Access = GENERIC_READ
    Share = FILE_SHARE_READ
    Disposition = OPEN_EXISTING
    Flags = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE Or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN Or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL _
            Or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY Or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM

    Debug.Print CreateFileW(StrPtr(sUnicode), Access, Share, ByVal 0&, Disposition, Flags, 0&)
```

Debug output  from a UNC file path was

```
\\?\UNC\kazw029530\Test Long File Folder Name\DAFF004 - ICON\201104 DAFF004 ICON SR3    LOMP3P WBS FGOV-5100035-01-10 110506 LOMP003P RiskAnalysis vA1 4.xls
The system cannot find the file specified.

4448
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not all Windows API functions support the `\\?\` prefix. CreateFileW does, GetFileSecurityW doesn't. The documentation specifies whether a function supports it.

So you have to use a file name without this prefix, which limits its length to `MAX_PATH` characters.